# R - power simulation for different regression models

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

I am creating a pseudo dataset from 'mvrnorm', and I would like to create new datasets for each simulation to compare the power of different regression models. I am currently hoping to compare three regression models: 1) linear regression, 2) mixed model, and 3) GEE.

Say my dataset is called "df". For each simulation iteration, I have

```
for(i in 1:nSim){
  plM = summary(lm(rowMeans(df ~ pred))$coef[2,4]
  pLMM = ...
  pGEE = ...}
```

so that my simulation loop returns different p-values (currently I getting the same p-values for each regression model).

How would I be able to create a new dataset in my simulation loop?

Thank you - your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `lm(rowMeans(df ~ pred))`. 1) You cannot get the row means of a formula; 2) you cannot regress a vector, there is no response.

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas, df here is actually from a matrix that has values inserted after an initial loop. The corrected formula would be lm(rowMeans(df) ~ pred).